# How to make bash script use a particular python version for executing a python script?

Tags: python, bash

I have python 2.6 and python installed on my Freebsd box. I want my bash script to execute a particular python script using python2.6 interpreter. It is showing import error....
Undefined symbol "PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably caused by the following.

Your script imports some third-party library which was compiled by an older python version.

To fix this, reinstall the up-to-date library.

Answer (score 0):

file.sh

```
result=`python ~/PythonScriptName.py`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path to the python version you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of the script, mention the shebang(#!)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Your script here
```

The error you got due to mismatch of compilation interpreter and running interpreter.This usually occurs with a Python installation compiled with Unicode UCS2 support running modules compiled against a Python installation with Unicode UCS4 support (or vis versa).You need to recompile/reinstall the scipy installation with exact the Python interpreter used for running your code.