# String processing issue using a Python intro text

Tags: python, string, input, indexing

What's wrong with this bit of Python?  Entering the names does not work.

```
def main():
    print("This program generates computer usernames.\n")

    # get user's first and last names
    first = input("Please enter your first name (all lowercase): ")
    last = input("Please enter your last name (all lowercase): ")

    # concatenate first initial with 7 chars of the last name
    uname = first[0] + last[:7]

    # output the username
    print("Your username is:", uname)

main()
```

Now, running the program results in this -- no idea what it's all about.

```
cd '/Users/ek/Desktop/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'                     '/Users/ek/Desktop/fun.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
EKs-Mac-mini:~ ek$ cd '/Users/ek/Desktop/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/ek/Desktop/fun.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1


This program generates computer usernames.

Please enter your first name (all lowercase): Bob


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ek/Desktop/fun.py", line 14, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/ek/Desktop/fun.py", line 5, in main
first = input("Please enter your first name (all lowercase): ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Bob' is not defined
EKs-Mac-mini:Desktop ek$
```

Comment: usually you tell us ... so whats wrong? ... at a guess this is python3 and you are using python2

Comment: We have no idea what your question is.   Give us a question that you are having.

Comment: One moment and I'll show you.

Comment: Why are you using pythonw vs. python?

Comment: Possibly related question: [No pythonw in Python 3.4 OS X 10.10?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30800426/3345375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing `input` to `raw_input` so your script will work in Python 2, you could add a shebang line so the Terminal shell will run your script in Python 3.

A shebang line tells the shell [(1) that the file is a shell script, (2) which Python interpreter to use, and (3) where to find that interpreter (the file path)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865189/3345375).

Then you should just be able to run `$ fun.py` in Terminal. You shouldn't need to specify `$ python3 fun.py`.

---

Two ways to write the shebang line.

1) Put this line at the top of your `fun.py` file:

`#! /usr/bin/env python3`

That is [the recommended way to write the shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463033/3345375). It works in UNIX-like operating systems (including Linux, Mac OS X, etc.)

2) Or, specify the complete absolute path to the location where Python 3 is installed. In your case:

`#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`

If you don't know the absolute path, find it using the Terminal command `$ which python3`.

---

**P.S.** As an alternative, [changing the default version of Python on your system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27789972/3345375) from Python 2 to Python 3  might also work. But it has other bad consequences [so don't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27789992/3345375).

Comment: (jibber jabber)
This program generates computer usernames.

Please enter your first name (all lowercase): Ed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ek/Desktop/#! :usr:bin:env python3.py", line 16, in =<module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ek/Desktop/#! :usr:bin:env python3.py", line 7, in main
    first = input("Please enter your first name (all lowercase): ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Ed' is not defined
EKs-MacBook-Pro:Desktop ek$

Comment: This happens with both versions of the shebang

Comment: Put some code in the script to find out what version of Python is running the script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1093331/3345375

Comment: `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`

Comment: Gotcha -- here's what we get:

Last login: Mon Jul  4 17:09:11 on ttys000
cd '/Users/ek/Desktop/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/ek/Desktop/username.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
EKs-Mac-mini:~ ek$ cd '/Users/ek/Desktop/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/ek/Desktop/username.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]
Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: Correction -- here it is with shebang: Last login: Mon Jul  4 17:13:28 on ttys000
EKs-Mac-mini:~ ek$ cd '/Users/ek/Desktop/' && '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3'  '/Users/ek/Desktop/username.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
Exit status: 0
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

Comment: So it's version 3.5.2. The `input` function should work in that version. I wish I knew why it doesn't...

Comment: At least we know that the shebang is working. Without it, the script is run with Python 2.7.10: `2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]`. With the shebang, the script is run with Python 3.5.2: `3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`

Comment: I think what you should do is [ask a new Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask): Post the Python code, including the shebang line, `import sys` and `print(sys.version)`; and also post the messages you're getting in Terminal. Then ask why the script seems to be running in Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Comment: Will do -- I noticed it was running version 3 as well from the output!  Thanks for all your help man, I'm upvoting you anyway before I start the new one.

Comment: Wish we could friend or follow people -- I really appreciate your going over this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, change `input` (which works in Python 3) to `raw_input` (which works in Python 2) and see what happens.

And to confirm which Python version you're using, run this Terminal command: `python --version`

Comment: Ehhh, I'm using Python 3.  Thanks though.

Comment: Crap, no, when I kick off the program it's using Python 2 on the terminal.  Any idea how to get the terminal to use Python 3?

Comment: Try running `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but if I have the program sitting there, how do I get it to run on python3 instead of python when I just double click on it?  How do I get the terminal to automatically do so?

Comment: What OS are you using? (Linux, Mac, Windows...)

Comment: I would try searching SO or Google for "Change default Python", "Switch default Python", or similar search terms.

Comment: OK. What specific program are you running as your Python environment? (The one you double-click on to open.)

Comment: The one originally described in my post.  Is there any command I can add at the start of a Python program to ensure that a specific version of Python is used?

def main():
    print("This program generates computer usernames.\n")

    # get user's first and last names
    first = input("Please enter your first name (all lowercase): ")
    last = input("Please enter your last name (all lowercase): ")

    # concatenate first initial with 7 chars of the last name
    uname = first[0] + last[:7]

    # output the username
    print("Your username is:", uname)

main()

Comment: I think here's the answer: In the first line of the Python script, [use a shebang (`#!`) followed by the absolute filepath to the version of Python you want to run](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21670658/3345375).

Comment: And on the flip side, check out this question: [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1093322/3345375)

Comment: One more thing: To find the path to version 3 of Python (to see where Python 3 is installed on your computer), run this Terminal command: `which python3`

Comment: I tried different permutations of the shebang, but it did not seem to work.  My Python 3.5 is installed under the rest of the apps, not like the Python 2.7 that came built in.

Comment: Hey jkdev, do you have any idea what the correct path should be if Python 3 is installed under apps?  Or should I move it somewhere else for the #! to work?  Pardon my ignorance, I'm a neophyte.

Comment: Try running `which python3` in Terminal.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3

I also checked the .bash_profile file and here is the version of python set:  
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: But when I open terminal and type "python --version" I get Python 2.7.10

Comment: How about when you type `python3 --version`?

Comment: (You'd probably get `Python 3.5`. Just making sure.)

Comment: I've posted [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38174826/3345375) based on these comments.